# Record log AND print on terminal while script runs

Tags: bash

I run a script and capture the log with the following command:

```
exec >1 log.txt 2>&1
set -x
#Body of the script
set +x
```

So far so good, but then when I run the script, I don't see any action in the terminal. All runs in the backgroud, but I would also like to se the "live" view of what is going on in my script, line by line.

I am thinking in something like in a program installation, where you see line by line what is done through this installation and get all those lines saved in the log file.

I appreciate any idea, thank you in advance.

Comment: [tee](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html)

Comment: With `bash`  something like `exec > >(tee log.txt) 2>&1`

Comment: Gilles and Leonardo's answer worked perfectly, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Simply' using (in place of you `exec` line):

```
exec &> >(tee log.txt)
```

As usually, `&` is a shorthand for `2>&1` in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

`tee` here, print to `STDOUT` *and* write to the log file at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tee` for this. It will write whatever comes from stdin both to stdout and to a file.

To pipe your entire script to it, you may want to wrap your entire script in a function:

```
set -x

main() {
  # Body of the script
}

main 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```